# BackPressed in Fragment not functioning properly

Tags: android, fragment, back-button

I have the following code:

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_color, container, false);
v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
v.requestFocus();
v.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (mMenu.isOpened()) {
                mMenu.closeMenu();
            } else {
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

When I press the back button, my menu closes like it should, but the app closes as well and it should not.

What am I doing wrong with what I have here? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to do a `System.out.println("KeyCode = " + keyCode);` - Suggestion: override the **Activity**'s `onBackPressed()` event, instead.

Comment: return true from function, which will mean you handled the back pressed otherwise your main activity will receive onbackpressed and your app will exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because finishing current activity is back key default behavior. You need to override this behavior by **returning true** in your onKeyListner. Below code should work for you.

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_color, container, false);
v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
v.requestFocus();
v.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (mMenu.isOpened()) {
                mMenu.closeMenu();
               //It says that you have handled back key
                return true;
            } else {
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: its good practice to upvote also if answer solves your problem :)